# Kentico 12 PageBuilder missing reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

In the _Layout.cshtml page, I receive this exception (IFeatureSet' does not contain a definition for 'PageBuilder' and no accessible extension method 'PageBuilder' accepting a first argument of type 'IFeatureSet' could be found).

[image]

Here is my code.

```
@{ 
    var editMode = string.Empty;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Kentico().PageBuilder().EditMode)
    {
        editMode = "kentico-page-builder";
    }
}
```

The project won't build because of it. The project has been upgraded to Kentico 12.0.30 even though the dll version says 12.0.0 (See attached image)
[image]

I have restarted Visual Studio, my computer, cleared temp files, cleared cache. Nothing fixes it. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

The PageBuilder() extension method is located in the **Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc** namespace, so you need to add this to your view:

`@using Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc`

Or, you can follow the guidance in #3 in the **Registering the page builder** section on https://docs.kentico.com/k12/developing-websites/page-builder-development and register the namespace in the web.config of the /Views folder:

`<add namespace="Kentico.PageBuilder.Web.Mvc"/>`